# Splitting multiple fields in a clean formula in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe that has multiple fields that all need to be split on a colon (:)

Each field should have two colons and be split into 3 new columns, but I found some instances where the fields have either more than two colons or less.

For most of my fields I have pre-defined the columns that the split will fall into.

But for two of the fields I have another formula that dynamically splits them based on however many colons are in the field because I was getting a error when I used the other format.
I am only showing four of the fields that I am splitting for readability, but I'm actually doing this to about 20 fields (the first technique).

Can I can do all of those splits in a cleaner way? You can see I'm using a different technique to split the "PARK_TIME" and the "PREVIEW_TIME"

This method works, it just is very clunky. I'm new to Python so any advice is much appreciated.

Also how can I cleanly convert all of these new fields from objects into integer data types?

Below is the code I am using:

```
# Column Split
df[['SPEED_OF_ANSWER1', 'SPEED_OF_ANSWER2', 'SPEED_OF_ANSWER3']] = df['SPEED_OF_ANSWER'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df[['3RD_PARTY_TALK_TIME1', '3RD_PARTY_TALK_TIME2', '3RD_PARTY_TALK_TIME3']] = df['3RD_PARTY_TALK_TIME'].str.split(':', expand=True)

parktime_df = df['PARK_TIME'].str.split(':', expand=True)
column_mapping = {}
for i in range(parktime_df.shape[1]):
    column_mapping[i] = f'PARK_TIME {i+1}'
parktime_df = parktime_df.rename(columns=column_mapping)
df = pd.concat([df, parktime_df], axis=1)


preview_df = df['PARK_TIME'].str.split(':', expand=True)
column_mapping = {}
for i in range(preview_df.shape[1]):
    column_mapping[i] = f'PARK_TIME {i+1}'
parktime_df = preview_df.rename(columns=column_mapping)
df = pd.concat([df, preview_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Its painful reading through your code. Consider adding a small example. ie probably the first few rows of your data. You do not have to do all the stuff you have expressed. The best thing to do is to simply read the data again using `:` as your separator/delimiter. Then you only need to clean the column names accordingly.